# Multiple Markers on google maps using an array in php and html. Markers not adding when in array but ok when the value is static

Tags: php, html, ajax

Markers not adding when in array but ok when the value is set to a static value. Is there some way to loop the array so that multiple markers will  be added?

```
function initMap() {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i< 5; i++){ //LOOP TO INCREMENT ARRAY
        var LatLng = {lat: <?php echo $lat[i]?>, lng: <?php echo $long[i]?>}; 
        //WORKING WHEN A STATIC NUMBER IS PLACED ON ARRAY
        //var myLatLng2 = {lat: <?php echo $lat[1]?> , lng: <?php echo $long[1]? >};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: LatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

            position: LatLng,//CREATE MARKER
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
        });

    }   
}
```

Comment: check weather value is coming is string or integer. If it is string then convert it to integer by using intval() function

Comment: `i` is a **JavaScript** variable, you can't use it in a **PHP** code !!

Comment: What does this question have to do with MySQL or the phpMyAdmin application?